# Postman: Check date equals yesterdays date

Tags: testing, automation, postman

I'm running a GET request using Postman and the JSON response is below:

```
{
    "Version": "1.0.524.0",
    "BuildName": "Live",
    "BuildDate": "04/12/2018 18:58:50.85 \r\n"
}
```

The build date increments by one each day and I want to write a script to check the date has been incremented and if it hasn't then its a failed test.

Currently I have this:

```
pm.test("Check Build Date", function (CheckDate) {
    pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.include("04/12/2018 18:58:50.85");
});
```

However I know if I run this script tomorrow it won't work and I will get the following error:

```
FAIL Check Build Date | AssertionError: expected '{"Version":"1.0.524.0","BuildName":"Live","BuildDate":"05/12/2018 18:58:50.85 \\r\\n"}' to include '04/12/2018 18:58:50.85'
```

Can anybody assist, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your response body is an object, like in your question, you can use `pm.response.json().BuildDate` and check that it equals that value.

```
pm.test("Check Build Date", () => {
    pm.expect(pm.response.json().BuildDate).to.equal("04/12/2018 18:58:50.85 \r\n");
});
```

Not sure why you have those `\r\n` values in string on that response, they seem in the wrong place to me.

---

To know that the day has incremented by 1, you would need to store the state of the last run and do a check against that. You could be that with setting it as an `environment` variable.

Send an initial request to get and set the `BuildDate`. You will now have that value to use in a `Check` request.

`pm.environemnt.set('lastBuildDate', pm.response.json().BuildDate)`

In the check request, you could have something like this:

```
const moment = require('moment')

let dateDiff = moment(pm.reponse.json().BuildDate).isAfter(pm.environment.get('lastBuildDate'))

pm.test("Check Build Date", () => {
    pm.expect(dateDiff).to.be.true
})
```

---

If you just want something that checks if the `BuildDate` is the after the time that that you are making the request - You could use something like this:

```
const moment = require('moment')

let dateNow  = moment().format("DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss.SS")
let dateDiff = moment(pm.response.json().BuildDate).isAfter(dateNow)

pm.test("Check Build Date", () => {
    pm.expect(dateDiff).to.be.true
})
```

This is obviously not what you want to do but I would suggest taking a look at the [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/) module as see if that is something in there that you can use for your use case.

Comment: Thanks for the response :) I want the script to test that the date has been incremented by one which it will be each day. Your suggested script will require editing each day which is what I am trying to avoid. Plus its including the build time which I don't want it to because the build time is random each night. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: My answer was an example of what you _could_ do, given your question. I mentioned on the answer that this will fail when the date changes. I didn't think it would be that string each time you run the check. Unless you keep some sort of state, how would you be able to know if the day has increase by one each. It would need something to check against.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot Danny - that was a great help :)

Comment: Ok, so you're accepting and up voting my answer then?

Comment: Accepted the answer :) I have a less than 15 reputation so my up vote doesn't display publicly.